# PLS-00457:"expressions have to be of SQL types" when defining a dynamic sql procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

i'm trying to call a procedure dynamically in the following way:

```
[..]
l_flag boolean;
l_sql := 'BEGIN ' || 'F017' || '(:l_flag); END;';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql
USING OUT l_flag;
[..]
```

The F017 procedure is just a stub:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE F017 ( outFlag out boolean)                                 
AS  

BEGIN    
dbms_output.put_line('      START - F017');

dbms_output.put_line('      END - F017');
END F017;
/
```

I keep getting the following error at the line where l_sql is defined:

```
PLS-00457:"expressions have to be of SQL types"
```

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:

This is the entire procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE individuaSegnalazioneSoggetto(
                                            projectContext projectContext_typ,
                                            codSoggettoCorrente number,
                                            sommaSaldi number
                                            )
AS
l_fatcaProcedures fatcaArray_typ;
l_codReport number;
l_flagSoggettoDaSegnalare boolean;
l_sql varchar2(4000);

BEGIN    
dbms_output.put_line('    START - individuaSegnalazioneSoggetto');
l_flagSoggettoDaSegnalare := false; 

l_fatcaProcedures := fatcaArray_typ('F017', 'F017', 'F017', 'F017', 'F017');    

FOR idx IN 1..l_fatcaProcedures.count
LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line ( '      Chiamata procedura ' || l_fatcaProcedures(idx));
    l_sql := 'BEGIN ' || l_fatcaProcedures(idx) || '(:l_flagSoggettoDaSegnalare); END;';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql
    USING OUT l_flagSoggettoDaSegnalare;          
    EXIT WHEN l_flagSoggettoDaSegnalare = true;
END LOOP;
dbms_output.put_line('    END - individuaSegnalazioneSoggetto'); 

END individuaSegnalazioneSoggetto;
/
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Please show entire code

Comment: i updated the question, thanks

Comment: F017 is just a stub in my project

Comment: Ok, it seems like i can't use a boolean variable as an OUT field in this situation. The problem disappears when i redefine the procedure to accept a varchar2. Can someone confirm this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute Immediate with Non-Sql type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912089/execute-immediate-with-non-sql-type)

Comment: Of course you could use `boolean` as out. Your code inside stub is probably generating this error (as I write before).  I guess you are using `Oracle 11g` in my instance `Oracle12c` everything works good. [Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a6405b8ff35c8d6af14a66489aff5c46)

Comment: It looks like the boolean variable this particular case can't be accepted. Not even as an IN variable. The code inside F017 is a stub, there is nothing that could cause this problem, as far as i can see.

Comment: Which version do you use? Copy my code from demo link and run in 12c if possible.

Comment: You are right, i'm using 11g. I can't test right now in 12c environment sorry. I'll keep this test for tomorrow. Thank you very much for now :)

Comment: If you read the documentation for the **EXECUTE IMMEDIATE Statement** for different Oracle versions, you will see that for 11.2 it says explicitly that the value of a bind variable cannot be TRUE, FALSE or NULL. For older versions (I checked 10.2) is says specifically that it can't be Boolean. However, for 12.1 it only says the value cannot be NULL; there is no restriction on the value being TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: thanks! That explains everything. If you turn this comment into an answer i will be glad to vote for it.

Comment: Try `'DECLARE l_flag boolean; BEGIN F017(l_flag); END;' for the statement`.